# Could I use MongoDB to attach DB in this way?

Tags: mongodb

We found a way to attach a db to another mongo instance,

that is, we copy db files like `test.*` from orgin mongo instance to dest mongo instance.

This way is worked if we restart mongo instance correct,

but once we found that this works even we keep mongo instance running without restart it.

So question: Can I just copy db to dest mongo instance without a restart step?

Comment: Do the databases you want to merge have the same collections or are the collections different?

Comment: @Philipp they are different

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the database files might not be a good idea, even though it appears to work.

A much cleaner method is to use the [`db.copyDatabase()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) shell method.

Another clean method would be to use [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) to export the source database to a file and then use [`mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to import it on the destination database.

Comment: Copying data files is perfectly accepted and valid method of moving your databases

Comment: sorry but , mongodump AND mongorestore is toooo slow.

Comment: the `StorageSize` of our db is about 400 GB

Comment: @jackalope how slow is "too slow"? How long does it take?

Comment: @Philipp may take ~1.5 hours if we just copy files to dest, but if use mongodump and mongorestore , it must take more than 12 hours.